# panic: gob: type elliptic.p256Curve has no exported fields

Tags: go, elliptic-curve, gob

I am trying to build a blockchain project when I'm catching an issue about gob Serialize.
I have a struct Wallet which uses elliptic.P256() Curve struct, and when I'm trying to serialize Wallet, a bug of no exported fields occured.

Really hope for some help.

There is my code.

```
const walletFile = "Wallets.dat"

type Wallets struct {
    WalletsMap map[string]*Wallet
}

type Wallet struct {
    PrivateKey ecdsa.PrivateKey
    PublicKey []byte
}

func (w *Wallets) SaveWallets() {
    var content bytes.Buffer

    gob.Register(elliptic.P256())

    encoder := gob.NewEncoder(&content)
    err := encoder.Encode(&w)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    err = ioutil.WriteFile(walletFile, content.Bytes(), 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

}


func NewWallets() (*Wallets, error) {
    if _, err := os.Stat(walletFile); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        wallets := &Wallets{}
        wallets.WalletsMap = make(map[string]*Wallet)
        return wallets, err
    }

    fileContent, err := ioutil.ReadFile(walletFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    var wallets Wallets
    gob.Register(elliptic.P256())
    decoder := gob.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(fileContent))
    err = decoder.Decode(&wallets)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    return &wallets, nil
}
```

The issue

```
2022/09/18 19:42:33 gob: type elliptic.p256Curve has no exported fields
panic: gob: type elliptic.p256Curve has no exported fields
```

Comment: You can either export the fields of `elliptic.p256Curve` or write custom function to Encode/Decode `elliptic.p256Curve`

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually trying to find an easier way, but it's difficult. I'll try to export the fields then.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Go version to **1.18.10 for less**. I have encountered the same issue due to the latest Go version i.e. 1.19.5

We need to downgrade the Go version the old way because Go doesn't provide anything like a fancy version manager.

Steps to downgrade Go Version:

1. **Uninstall the existing Go version**

   To uninstall go, locate where Go is on your system.

   `$where go` This command will locate the program
   file in the user path.

   To uninstall, delete the `/usr/local/go` directory or the source
   directory which you have received as output in the previous command.
   Use command `$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/go` to delete the Go directory.

   To confirm run the command `$ go version`,
   system will prompt *"command go not found"* if you have successfully deleted Go ditrectory.
2. **Install the new version**

   Go to the [downloads](https://go.dev/dl/) page and download the version release(choose installer instead of Archive to make things easy for yourself) which is compatible with your OS and Architecture. Unzip and extract the package installer and the new Go version is now installed in your system.

After that, you will need to restart your terminal for the change to take effect.
To check if you have installed Go successfully, run the command `$go version`. The command prints the installed version of Go. Also make sure that `GOROOT` and `GOPATH` haven't changed.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution here

In go1.20, the serialization of god requires reflection, while there is an interface in the attribute of type `ecdsa.PrivateKey`, which may not be usable.

How to solve it? `Ecdsa.PrivateKey` maybe have a specialized serialization method.

The demo is as follows:

```golang
type Wallet struct {
    PrivateKey ecdsa.PrivateKey
    PublicKey  []byte
}

func (w *Wallet) Save() {
    filename := filepath.Join(constcoe.Wallets, string(w.Address())+".wlt")

    privKeyBytes, err := x509.MarshalECPrivateKey(&w.PrivateKey)
    utils.Handle(err)
    privKeyFile, err := os.Create(filename)
    utils.Handle(err)
    err = pem.Encode(privKeyFile, &pem.Block{
        // Type:  "EC PRIVATE KEY",
        Bytes: privKeyBytes,
    })
    utils.Handle(err)
    privKeyFile.Close()
}


func LoadWallet(address string) *Wallet {
    filename := filepath.Join(constcoe.Wallets, address+".wlt")
    if !utils.FileExists(filename) {
        utils.Handle(errors.New("no wallet with such address"))
    }

    privKeyFile, err := os.ReadFile(filename)
    utils.Handle(err)
    pemBlock, _ := pem.Decode(privKeyFile)
    utils.Handle(err)
    privKey, err := x509.ParseECPrivateKey(pemBlock.Bytes)
    utils.Handle(err)
    publicKey := append(privKey.PublicKey.X.Bytes(), privKey.PublicKey.Y.Bytes()...)
    return &Wallet{
        PrivateKey: *privKey,
        PublicKey:  publicKey,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be trying to do here is serialize a P256 curve from the `crypto/elliptic` package. The issue is that the `P256()` function returns an interface called `elliptic.Curve`.

What this error is telling you is that the underlying type of the `elliptic.Curve`, in this case `elliptic.p256Curve`, doesn't have any fields that are exported (named with the first letter capitalized). Go's `reflect` package, which `encoding/gob` uses, only works on exported fields.

You might want to try using `crypto/elliptic`'s [`Marshal()`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/elliptic#Marshal) or [`GenerateKey()`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/elliptic#GenerateKey) functions.

Comment: Thanks! You explained this really clearly that I totally understood my problem! I'm actually trying to serialize a curve, but some no exported fields in crypto/elliptic package really stopped me. I can only solve the problem by changing all the fields into exported or I may try not to serialize any curve.

Comment: Unfortunately, since you don't have control of the `crypto/elliptic` package, you can't make the fields exported, since in order to do so, you'd have to change their names so they start with a capital letter. Based on the function signatures in the `elliptic` package, I believe you're not supposed to serialize the entire curve, but rather a point on the curve or a generated key.

Comment: Well, I finally give up serialize the entire curve to solve my problem~

Answer (score -1):

Its problem in 1.9.* versions of Go. Just install 1.8.7 for example. Everything gonna work fine after this)